# md5 String and File different

Tags: shell, hashsum

Why do I become a different hash when I try:
`md5 <<< "Hello"`
`md5 -s "Hello"`
Is it because of a possible line break in the first example?

Comment: When in doubt, dump your data. `od -xa <<< 'Hello'` or `xxd <<< 'Hello'` will show you an extra trailing newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heredocs (thats what `<<<` is called) in bash always end with a newline character. There is no way to disable this behavior. This newline character is what is throwing off the checksum.

Comment: Note that `bash` copied that feature (called _herestring_ not _heredoc_) from `ksh93` which itself copied it from `zsh` which itself copied it from the Plan 9 shell `rc`. `rc` did not add the trailing newline character. `ksh93`, `zsh` and `bash` do.